# C2DM with lower API level?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

For C2DM to work, a device clearly must be at API level 8. However, does this really require that the application be compiled at that level? None of the code to work with C2DM requires any APIs at level 8. So would it be possible to have an app at a lower level, maybe API level 4 or 6, and have it try to do the C2DM registration? Maybe the registration fails on devices that are at a lower API level, and hopefully this can be detected so that an alternate mechanism could be used. However, shouldn't registration succeed for a device at API level 8 or higher? What I'm trying to do here is take advantage of C2DM while still compiling at level 4, so that my app can reach the most number of users. Ideally this is possible, and I can detect when the device is not capable of C2DM, and react accordingly.

Comment: cn u help me for push notification and send some code for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK` I believe to determine the highest level API the device supports and handle API 8 and <8 separately without requiring the user to be at a certain API level to install the app.

Comment: That is probably more useful than trying to catch an exception. I'm experimenting currently to see if the original idea works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this now - android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK is deprecated now, but you can use android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT instead, like so:

```
    int current_sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (current_sdk >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        registerForC2DM(activity);
    }
```

Here is a reference on all the version codes you can use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Comment: one thing about using VERSION_CODES is that if you are on a lower API, it will be undefined.  ex: if you are on API 7, and you are trying to use the FROYO constant, it will be undefined.  It's kind of dumb, but it seems better to just check vs '8' than FROYO, so you can support backwards compatibility.

Comment: @triad no, constants are evaluated at compile time and the value of the constant is put into your dex-file instead of a reference.